# more models on a mvc3 page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, models

Could I have more models on a razor page?
for example when I have more grid controls each with an area(a template) for editing the data,and after that i want to save the data and see it in the grid.

Comment: No, just use nested models within a super model.

Comment: @DaveA, I'm afraid you, So I wont write an example code :)

Comment: LOL! @AliRızaAdıyahşi, go at it. You have my blessing!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the example below (this is a very over simplified example):

```
public class AnimalDataViewModel
{
    public List<Dog> DogData { get; set; }

    public List<Cat> CatData { get; set; }

    public List<Mouse> MouseData { get; set; }

    public AnimalDataViewModel()
    {
        this.DogData = new List<Dog>();
        this.CatData = new List<Cat>();
        this.MouseData = new List<Mouse>();
    }
}
```

Then in your action method:

```
public ActionResult DisplayAnimalDataGrids()
{
    AnimalDataViewModel model = new AnimalDataViewModel();

    model.DogData = this.myDataService.GetDogData();
    model.CatData = this.myDataService.GetCatData();
    model.MouseData = this.myDataService.GetMouseData();

    return View(model);
}
```

Then in your view:

```
@model AnimalDataViewModel

@Html.Grid(Model.DogData)
@Html.Grid(Model.CatData)
@Html.Grid(Model.MouseData)
```

Comment: in the view,i want to show also some kind of editor templates for the models and use them for editing the grid information.can i use Html.EditorFor or other ideas?

Comment: It depends, `EditorFor` is useful when originally rendering the page, so you could include the flattened model for a singular Dog, Cat and Mouse in the main model.  Then use `Html.EditorFor(Model.Dog)`, etc. in the view.  Although if you're going down the single screen app route, you probably want to look into rendering partials, calling action methods that return JSON objects and filling in form details (and saving) all using jQuery and more AJAX.  In MVC the simple page to page submission is always a much easier route than single screen apps.

Comment: sometimes is not my call,i have to do it as they ask me to do and they want a grid and below some edit template,and i can be multiple grids on other pages with the same ideea.and my choise was to use a partial view loaded with jquery.load() this way i still use some mvc advantages.